# error running index.js for socket.io on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift, amazon-web-services, socket.io

I have been trying for some time to get my index.js script running on my AWS EC2 server for my chat app.  I have updated Node to the latest version (9.4.0) and NPM also.

When I try to run the script using:

```
sudo node index.js
```

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

Reading on the internet I managed to circumvent that by running the script using the following line:

```
sudo node --harmony index.js
```

However now I'm getting the following error and have no way to resolve it:
(the little carat pointing to the error location is just under the first close bracket just after the equals sign below)

const native = (() => {
                 ^

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/example/node/node_modules/ws/index.js:9:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

I'm not at all an expert on node and don't do a lot of backend programming.  Just trying to get the index file running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` has been supported in Node for some time now. Are you sure you're using last the version of Node? Can you check the returned value from `node -v`?

Comment: hi.  thanks for your reply.  when I try node -v it says 9.4.0 however I just ran my script without sudo and everything worked fine.  running sudo node -v returned version v0.10.48.  so I guess I need to figure out why sudo is using a different version and how to resolve that.  thanks very much for your help

Comment: My advice would be to uninstall the user version of Node (9.4.0) and then update the "sudo" version, better with some version manager like n: https://github.com/tj/n

That is, if you want to run Node with sudo.